# Insert elements in between in numpy array after a certain value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
data=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]).
```

And I want to fill in the gaps of zeroes between ones, where ones are separated with no more than 2 zeroes. The output should be:

```
data=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]).
```

I write the code and it apparently does the job, but I get an error.

````
    if (data[i]==1) & (data[i+3]==1):
      for j in range(3):
        data[i+j]=1
       if data[-1]==1:   #If 1 is at the end of the array it should not do anything, but I guess it does not work.
         pass```

IndexError: index 38 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 38.

Could you help me to improve?
````

Comment: you get this error because when `i=37` (i.e. when you read to the end of your array), `j` can be larger than 0, exceeding the length of the array.

Comment: Your code won't fill `[ ... 0,0,0,1,0,1, ...]` or is that data that can't occur?  As per the answer below, can your data have more than one consecutive `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to avoid using loops by shifting the values in data instead of looping.  The code below copes with gaps of 1 or 2 zeroes and groups of consecutive 1s.

```
import numpy as np 

def fill_zeros( data ):
    result = data.copy()
    temp = np.zeros_like( data )
    temp[2:] = data[2:] & data[:-2]   # Gaps of one.
    result[ 1:-1 ] |= temp[2: ]       # temp shifted left one.
    temp[:] = 0                       # reset temp to zeroes
    temp[3:] = data[3:] & data[:-3]   # Gaps of two
    result[1:-2] |= temp[ 3:]         # Shift temp 2 left
    result[2:-1] |= temp[ 3:]         # Shift temp 1 left
    return result
```

To test:

```
data=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0])
data
#  array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
#      0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

fill_zeros( data )
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
#      0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: This is nice. But I started with a loop because in my real dataset I have a vector of 1000 000 values, where I suppose to have a square wave with amplitude 0 to 1 (100 k sequence of 1 and 50 k sequence of 0). The problem is that where I should have a sequence of '1s' continuously , I have the jumping '1'. 1, 1024*0, 1, 1024*0, 1... What I am looking is to get rid of those '0' insertions in the period of amplitude of 1. Sorry for not explaining this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that there are not any two consecutive 1's

```
# find index of first 1's
idx = np.where(np.logical_and(data[:-2] == 1, data[2:] == 1))  
idx = idx[0][::2]

# set two elements after first 1's to 1
data[idx+1] = 1
data[idx+2] = 1
```